# Neo4j 2.3.1 not releasing handles on import files

Tags: neo4j

After upgrading from Neo4j 2.2.5 to Neo4j 2.3.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 with Java 8.45, we encountered a problem with file handles. When running the command shown at the bottom of this post using either the web interface or neo4jshell.bat, the cypher completes successfully and a process monitor trace confirms that Java successfully closed the file. However, I am unable to move that csv file because the file is open in another process. Handle.exe confirms that Java still has a read-write handle on that file.

When I run the same process against a Neo4j 2.2.5 graph on the same machine with the same file, Java does not retain the read-write handle on the csv file. We will need to revert to 2.2.5 until this issue is resolved. The only application change we made during the upgrade from 2.2.5 to 2.3.1 was to accommodate the new file reference format (file:///x://filename.csv vs. file:x:/filename.csv).

Are there other actions we can take short of restarting the service or stopping and starting the drive to force Java to close this file? I understand that Neo4jShell.bat is deprecated in favor of the powershell commands, but ultimately the issue is that Java is retaining the file handle, so changing the method of delivering the cypher command can't improve the way Java is handling the csv file. I've run the same cypher from both the web interface and neoj4shell.bat and gotten the same result.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 3000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM "file:///x://filename.csv"
AS line
MATCH (a:node {id : line.id}), (b:othernode {id : line.other_id})
WITH a, b
WHERE shortestPath((a)-[:PREVIOUS]->(b)) is null
CREATE (a)-[:PREVIOUS]->(b);
```

Comment: does it also happen without periodic commit? And when you only load the file and `return count(*) `

Comment: Hi Michael,

I ran without the periodic commit and replacing the create with a return count(*) and got the same issue. Interestingly, this issue happens intermittently, but once Java takes the read-write handle, it won't release it unless I stop Java or reset the drive. I took a file that Java had successfully released yesterday and tried it again today and got this same behavior where Java retains the read-write handle. So neither the file contents, the method of submitting the cypher, nor whether the command contains a create or a return explains why Java retains handles on some files.

Comment: Update: the issue remains in Neo4j 2.3.3